# Take value from URL with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have this URL :

```
http://sath3g.altervista.org/jsonint.html+?id=4545ga
```

In which way i can take the value of the id with jquery or javascript???
The most important thing is that i can not use php !

Comment: I take it you have not tried to Google "get url with javascript" ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
"http://sath3g.altervista.org/jsonint.html+?id=4545ga".split('=')[1];
```

Or more particular:

```
"http://sath3g.altervista.org/jsonint.html+?id=4545ga".match(/id=(\d+)/).pop();
```

Comment: @user3584684: SO requires a minimal understanding of the problem. What is unclear to you in Amit's anwer?

Comment: I don't understand nothing. If is possible can you make me an example?

Comment: @AmitJoki: your first answer does not work when having multiple parameters, the second one does not work with a-z.